# Calculating lateral load requirement for canopy

Tags: pergola

I am adding a 16' x 15' canopy to a patio consisting of two 7.5x16 panels of draped cloth suspended from steel cables, like the product you see here: https://www.infinitycanopy.com/

I would like to support the canopy from a steel post and beam system to match the existing design of the space. Like so: |¯|¯|, 10' vertical and 7.5' spacing between posts.

What I'm trying to determine is the lateral load on the top beams and the minimum size steel bar I can use.

The cables are hand tensioned and the panels weigh a total of 75lbs. The canopy will be retracted when not in use and won't be used in significant winds.

I know the safe bet would be to use 4x4" steel and bury 5' in concrete but I am hoping I can get away with something a little more delicate looking, 2x2 bars would be ideal from a design standpoint but 3x3 would be acceptable.

Anyways, is there a way to estimate the lateral load I need to account for?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would only try the 2x2s with guy wires.  Thick 3x3s should be okay.  Tension does not sound like it be much with just cables and cover, but it does add up more than you figure.  It is nice it won't be used in wind, but we all know stuff happens and then we are up to our necks.